# How Change GJS App output filename with meson

Tags: javascript, gtk, meson-build, gjs, gnome-builder

i have made a graphic software with JavaScript and GJS with GNOME builder. The problem is that whenever I want to run the software, I have to enter the application ID in the terminal (e.g. org.example.app), which is inconvenient.

I changed the `output` section in `src/meson.build` file, but when i run it i get this error:

```
(exampleapp:2411): Gjs-WARNING **: 17:31:11.727: JS ERROR: ImportError: Unable to load file from: resource:///org/example/app/js/main.js (The resource at “/org/example/app/js/main.js” does not exist)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected executable name for a GJS application, per the [Package Specification](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/master/doc/Package/Specification.md).

If you want to create an alias for it, you should probably just use a symbolic link (e.g. `org.foo.Bar` => `foo-bar`).